GetMessagesReactionsRequest - distinguish reactions between 2 users
Is there a system to distinguish the reaction of one user from another? I'm testing with two my personal telegram accounts, but the terminal always gives me the same username, but in reality they are 2 users that makes reaction, not the same one.

I test with this
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetMessagesReactionsRequest
from telethon.tl.types import DocumentAttributeFilename

api_id = '2++++'
api_hash = 'f++++'
channel_id = -100+++  

client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)

async def main():
    async with client:
        channel_entity = await client.get_input_entity(channel_id)
        messages = await client.get_messages(channel_entity, limit=100)
        me = await client.get_me()

        for message in messages:
            reactions = await client(GetMessagesReactionsRequest(channel_entity, [message.id]))
            if reactions.updates:  # check if the reactions list is not empty
                for update in reactions.updates:
                    if hasattr(update, 'reactions'):
                        for reaction_count in update.reactions.results:
                            content = message.message if message.message else "No caption"
                            if hasattr(message, 'media') and message.media:
                                if hasattr(message.media, 'document') and message.media.document:
                                    for attr in message.media.document.attributes:
                                        if isinstance(attr, DocumentAttributeFilename):
                                            content = attr.file_name
                            username = me.username if me.username else "ignoto"
                            print(f"Post ID: {message.id} - Content: {content[:50]} - Reaction: {reaction_count.reaction.emoticon}, Count: {reaction_count.count}, User: @{username}")

client.loop.run_until_complete(main())


If official clients can't do it, you probably can't do it either. Most likely, you only see yourself, so you can know that you can remove your own reaction.

@Lonami so if both accounts are mine should I run the code with both the ID API and the HASH API? or first with an id-hash pair and then the other pair of credentials from my 2 different accounts?

The developer of an application (or in your case script) creates the API ID/hash pair. As many users (or in your case accounts) as you want can use that application. They don't even need to be the same as the developer.
